# Transfer contacts between iPhone 4 and old feature phone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I recently upgraded to an iPhone 4 from an old Samsung SGH-G600 and want to transfer contacts. At the shop they offered to do it for me for £15 which I thought was ridiculous so I'm hoping there's a way to do this other than manual.

The iPhone is non-jailbroken and the old Samsung phone does have Bluetooth.

Comment: Do you have any way to get the contacts onto a PC? I'm surprised they want to charge so much for just transferring contacts.

Comment: @bassplayer7 So was I, there might be a USB cable some where by I was hoping for a direct phone-to-phone route

Comment: I'm very confident there are no USB cables/software combinations that will allow you to directly transfer the contacts over. Even if you were to use the iPhone's USB cable and adapt it to mini-USB (if your old Samsung supports it), I don't think that the iPhone (or Samsung) would recognize each other enough to transfer contacts.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to transfer files via bluetooth between iPhone and other smart phones.You will need to transfer the contacts from your old Samsung SGH-G600 into your computer first, and then sync it to your iPhone 4. I don't know what operating system your computer is running, but normally you can do as the following steps:

1. Open iTunes
2. Use USB cable to connect your Samsung to computer, copy the contacts to your iTunes library.
3. Then plug in your iPhone 4 to computer using the included USB cable, select the content you wanna sync in iTunes under Devices on the left-hand side.
4. Click Apply, in the lower-right corner of the screen, to sync.

You can find some useful information from apple's support:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1386